# Illustrator- saving svgs effectively

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I've drawn a rather large diagram with illustrator, it is a truly massive thing. My idea is that I want to have it on a web page within a little scrollable image viewer. But that comes later. First things first; How do I save the image as an svg and keep it looking the way it looks in illustrator?

What I mean is here is how it looks in illustrator:

[image: ills image]

![how it looks in illustrator - http://tinypic.com/r/o0s1vr/5]

And here is how it looks as an svg opened up in a web browser:

[image: ie image]

![browser image]

I hope you can see my problem here. The positioning of some elements gets thrown really off-kilter.
Any idea what the problem is and what I'm doing wrong? Any advice on how to do things right?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the main problem is the missing font.  If you can't guarantee that the font will be available to the browser, then you have two options:

1. Convert the text to outlines when you save
2. Embed the font as an SVG font.  In the options window when you save.  Look in the fonts section.  Change the 'Type' to 'SVG'.  This should embed the font as part of the file.

   See this page for more info: http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2013/09/exporting-svg-illustrator.html

Comment: ah. saving to outlines seems to sort it. Thanks. Didnt realise it would be something so simple.
Is there no way to use fancy fonts on svgs? I don't particularly need to on this image but typesetting can be important for some images.

Comment: Option #2 is the closest to what you want.  I haven't tried using web fonts (@font-face etc), but that may work also.